# Should _GNU_SOURCE be defined throughout the project?

Tags: c, gnu

If I'm planning to use something that is only provided after declaring `_GNU_SOURCE`, do I ***need*** to declare `_GNU_SOURCE` at the top of ***all*** source files in the project?

Is it ***safe*** to only declare it at the top of any source files that require it?

My initial concern is related to type declarations... it's of course possible that a `struct` changes shape after defining `_GNU_SOURCE`, but is that likely, or is it guaranteed that such things "*will not change shape*"?

For example, if I use a `struct` to declare a variable in one file (with `_GNU_SOURCE`), and then use that variable in another (without `_GNU_SOURCE`), is guaranteed that I will not run into problems?

---

In this case I'm after `pthread_tryjoin_np()`.

Comment: if your compiler is `gcc`, then you can use the option: `-std=gnu11` Then the compiler will act as if each of the `feature test macros` for glibc are written, including the `__GNU_SOURCE` macro.  Then you never have to worry about such details as indicated in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is safe to declare it only in files that need it.

After all, the whole point is that some code would break if was defined, but it still needs to be linked with code that uses it.

As @IanAbbott notes below, exception is when you use some of the varying types in your interface. Then you need to keep the definition consistent for the modules that use it. E.g. `off_t` becomes, under `_GNU_SOURCE`, alias for `off64_t`, so if you then include the same header with `_GNU_SOURCE` turned off, it will define different functions.

That said, within a project there is really not much reason not to define it everywhere, because once you define it in any file, you depend on it. So defining it locally only helps anything if it is in an optional component or if you have alternates for other systems that use functions specific to those other systems instead.

Comment: It depends. Defining `_GNU_SOURCE` also selects large file support, affecting types such as `off_t`, and changing which functions the "plain" functions that use `off_t` (such as `lseek`, `pread`, etc.) map to. That may or may not be a problem, depending on the code that uses them, and whether the target has native large file support without requesting it explicitly.